# Cox survival statistic on Infractions made by bus companies

Tags: probability, python, predictive-models, cox-model, algorithms

I have a Dataset that represents if in some date a bus company made any kind of traffic infraction, and how many infractions were made. This is a view of the dataset where i have the Companies, the date, how many km were traveled by the buses of that company, how many infractions were made and if in that day that company made infractions (1 if yes, 0 if not)

[image]

I'm wondering if it makes sense using Cox Survival statistic in this kind of scenario to know what are the probabilities in days, weeks and months that a company would make a infraction, and what are the companies that have more probability of it. Cox need a survival time or time until event, but its not like from time 0 there would be more infractions, its not dependent on how much time has passed from time 0. Is more like a pattern in certain dates.

Answer (score 0):

A survival model is important when there is censoring of times to events. You don't have that here.

What you have is a count outcome for each observation day, and associated predictor variables. A count-based model such as a Poisson or negative-binomial generalized linear model would be a useful choice.